# Approach to restarting Google Drive periodically under Windows

Tags: windows, google-drive

I run GoogleDrive on an unatteded Windows 7 machine. Periodically I have to restart Google Drive as GD gets itself into a state where it stops syncing. Restarted GD fixes the issue.

Has anyone got a BAT file or similair approach that I can schedule to do the restart of GD so I don't have to do it manually?

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution? Is it working?

Comment: I have not tried it. I do know the ping part will do the trick as I have used that as a way to pause between requests. GD has been stable for a couple of months so until I know it breaks regularly I am loathe to mess with it.

Comment: I have configured this on a server but sometime it hangs. I wonder if terminating the program with taskkill may lead into data corruption!

Comment: What config are you using to start Drive? run as a service or task scheduler? If any of those, coul you point out what settings are you using both to start the exe and what advanced settings in drive client? Thanks!

Comment: Don't bother, see my answer below, switch to a low-cost 3rd party client with support who will actually help you resolve any issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to automatically run periodically, just use Task Scheduler (search for it in the Start Menu) to run a batch script.

The batch script should contain:

> taskkill /f /im googledrivesync.exe
>   ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 > nul
>   start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"
>   exit

The ping command is there just to add a delay between killing and restarting googledrivesync.exe

Answer (score 0):

Task CMD : C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe EXEC_HIDEN_CMD_GOOGLE_SYNC.vbs

Text for file named EXEC_HIDEN_CMD_GOOGLE_SYNC.vbs :

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run ".\RestartGoogleSync.bat",0,True

Text for file named RestartGoogleSync.bat :

taskkill /f /im googledrivesync.exe

timeout 5 >> nul

start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"

exit

Put All in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder.